# Concat two env variables in WSO2 Dataservice

Tags: wso2, dataservice

Can I concat two variables in WSO2 Dataservice?

Something like

```
<config id="DBConf">
        <property name="url">$SYSTEM:DB_URL$;$SYSTEM:DB_NAME</property>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can add multiple environment variables. But as a workaround maybe you can concat these two variables where you are exporting these environment variables.

```
export FULL_DB_URL=$DB_URL;$DB_NAME
```

then in dataservice

```
<config id="DBConf">
        <property name="url">$SYSTEM:FULL_DB_URL</property>
</config>
```

Comment: Yup, I concluded the same answer, I even named variable the same way as you did. Thanks